# Is there a Desktop Manager similar to Virtual Dimension?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, virtual-desktop

Currently I'm using a very old version of [Virtual Dimension](http://virt-dimension.sourceforge.net/) with a several years old code base as desktop manager in **Windows 7**. It's open source, and has several benefits compared to several other desktop managers.

- Customizable amount of desktops (arrangeable in rows and columns)
- Multi screen support
- Overview window for all tasks on all desktops with drag and drop support to rearrange windows on different desktops
- Customizable keybindings for common actions (like in GNOME: move windows to next/prev. desktop, switch desktops, maximize horizontally / vertically etc.)
- It adds a new menu entry to each window which allows configuring its look and feel. These settings can be saved and applied to several windwos etc.

[image: Virtual Dimension Menu]

Does anyone know a similar desktop manager with at least these features? Has anyone heard of updates or clones of this project? Is anyone interested in continueing the development?
Preferrably it shouldn't be a shell replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some alternatives that I found, but I'm not sure if they meet your criteria.

- http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=produkt
- http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/
- http://windowspager.sourceforge.net/
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx
- http://vdm.codeplex.com/

These were found at [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/virtual-dimension/)

I hope one of these fits your needs :)